# Upgrading .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to update my project from .net framework 2 and asp.net 2 to the newest versions. Is there any possible issues I may have?

Comment: I can't find it anymore, but I know MS published the list of breaking changes. You could try finding it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will very much depend on the application you are trying to upgrade. Is it using heavy interop? Is it using third party assemblies not compatible with the latest version of the framework? ... For general upgrade notes you may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx). The [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes) is also a must read before going ahead. Needless to say that you should have a backup before taking any *irreversible* steps in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the project. Upgrade the copy. See what happens!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Framework 4 and your project references any .NET version 1 or 1.1 assemblies you will have to fix this issue through the config file.

Answer (score 0):

We recently updated all of our projects to use .net 4 (newest version).  The only problem we ran into was that ALL of our applications needed to be upgraded to .net 4 as well.  This includes desktops, servers (IIS), and other projects that might interact.

However, besides that it is very painless and easy

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get started:

[ASP.NET 4.0 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes)